# Cant copy attachment from Lotus to hard drive

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

We developed a database for corporate file sharing. And there is one little problem:
Users choose the file (attachment in rich text field), right click on it and choose "Copy" option. Then they go to windows' explorer, right click at empty space, but the option "paste" is not available.
"My Lotus is broken", - they say...
Is this any way do grant users ability copy-paste attachment from Lotus to hard drive? Or they have to use "Save" option and there is no other way?

Comment: Copy/paste is not possible, but they can drag the attachment and drop it to a file system folder or their desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the right click and "Copy" something within a Notes document, then it depends on the state, the document is in what happens. If the document is in read- mode then usually the document itself is copied into clipboard. Only Lotus Notes can do anything with this clipboard and other applications will not allow you to paste it.

If the document is in edit- mode, then the selected content will be copied into the clipboard.  This can be the attachment, but again only for pasting in Lotus Notes. For other applications there will be only the attachment name in the clipboard.

The solution is simple: Just tell your users to NOT use "Copy", but "Save" or "Save all" from the same context menu. That's the way how Lotus Notes works...

If you need to have a "Copy" action there, then you could make your own context menu, and "mimic" what happens... But I would not do that.